# Launch an android application using by hardware button press

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediasession, media-buttons

Thank you for reading my question and please don't mention the older answers because I went through every bit of old ones in here that nothing work out. And I tried to find something from [Responding to media buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons) in android developer documentation but I didn't understand it. Please be kind enough to support me!

I am developing an android application for blind people Therefore I want this application launch by using specific hardware button clicks. How can I do this? Any advice, help, pointers welcome!

Comment: Another way to open apps would be voice command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create broadcastreceiver:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import android.util.Log;

    public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int volume = (Integer)intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
            Log.i("Tag", "Action : "+ intent.getAction() + " / volume : "+volume);      
        }
    }
```

Create App class that extends Application class and register this receiver. If it wont help - you will need to create separate service that will listen to user actions.